# Better to have infinities in limits or integrands (`NIntegrate`)?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm using `ListPlot` to plot the integral of a function with respect of the function's second variable: 
`ListPlot[NIntegrate[integrand[x, #], {x, -Infinity, 0}]&/@Range[10, 20]]`. The integral involves products of huge and tiny numbers.

The question is whether it is (generally) better to have the infinities in the limits of integration $$\int_0^\infty dx$$ or is it (in general) better to make a change of variables, e.g. letting $$z=e^{-x}$$ so that the integral becomes 
$$\int_0^1 dz$$ with the possible infinities now in the integrand?

Comment: Again, it depends. For instance, one of the built-in methods in `NIntegrate[]` is double-exponential quadrature, which performs a variable substitution that turns any integral into a doubly-infinite integral with rapid decay at the ends. On the flip side: apart from your suggested substitution, another useful one is $u=\tan x$…